# Custom Http headers in Angular 2 for every request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-http

In my Angular 2 application, I'm trying to use *Http* (`@angular/http`) to make requests to my API. For these requests to work, I need certain headers to be added to every request I make to the API (including a JWT header).

What I'd like to do is have an *API* class that takes care of creating the Http requests and some error handling and validation etc.

As it turns out, however, I cannot use the *Http* class from my *API* class, as it will come up with the following error;
[image: error]

## user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {User} from "../models/User";
import {API} from "../API";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class UserService
{
    constructor (private http : Http) {}

    getProfile (user : User)
    {
        let api = new API (this.http);

        return api.doRequest ('/user/' + user.id + '/profile');
    }
}
```

## API.ts

```
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

export class API
{
    ...

    constructor (private http : Http) {}

    doRequest (url : string, method : string, data?)
    {
        let headers = {...};
        let options = new RequestOptions ({ headers: new Headers (headers), ... } );

        return this.http.get (url, data, options)
            .catch ((error) => { ... } );
    }
}
```

Things work better when using *Http* straight from the *UserService*, however.

Is there a way to fix this, or perhaps a better way to achieve the desired result? Should I just extend *Http*?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use http within the API class, and not pass it in at all (that somehow looks wonky, I don't think it's a good idea to pass around an instance of an injected service...why not just inject it into the class that's going to use it)? And wouldn't you need to call API.doRequest?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using **append()** method to add headers and then pass it to request object as below

```
 doRequest (url : string, method : string, data?)
    {
        headers= new Headers();
        headers.append(name1,value1);
        headers.append(name2,value2);
        ....
        let options = new RequestOptions ({ headers: headers, ... } );

        return this.http.get (url, data, options)
            .catch ((error) => { ... } );
    }
```

Comment: I did not test it in Angular4

Answer (score 0):

That's the way today setting HTTP headers (Angular > 4):

Import:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
```

and usage:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value");
```

Notice that we are building the headers object by chaining successive set() methods. This is because HttpHeaders is immutable, and its API methods do not cause object mutation.

Instead, a call to set will return a new HttpHeaders object containing the new value properties. So this means that **the following will NOT work**:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders ();
headers.set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value")
```